# Negative sign in front of a number

Tags: arithmetic, real-numbers

Does $-a$ mean $(-1)a$ for a real number $a$?

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a legitimate question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  -a means both (-1)a and 0 - a, which are usually the same thing.

Note if a is negative -a is positive.  Ex.  -(-7) = 7.  And 0 -(-7) = 7.

You should try to mark this take for the appropriate subject though.

Comment: Also note that $0=-0$.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small clarification: "$-$" is the abbreviation of "$-1\cdot{}$", hence $-a=-1\cdot a$.  Parentheses are not necessary.